# Is it possible to pass two columns in IN clause or any another possible way

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I want to filter my data in oracle database like this, I know this query is wrong is htere any other possible way to do this?
Currently i am trying to do like this.

```
   SELECT apd.first_name,
       apd.middle_name,
       apd.last_name,
       apd.first_thi_nme,
       apd.middle_thi_nme,
       apd.last_thi_nme
FROM applicant_detail apd
WHERE apd.application_number IN
    ( SELECT **apd.application_number,
               apd.industry_type_cde**
     FROM a_detail apd,
          a_type apt
     WHERE apt.application_number=apd.application_number
       AND apt.identification_code=apd.identification_code
       AND apt.guarantor_type='I' )
```

// I have to find recode on these two column base where both of them same them return unique or any other way to pass these `apd.application_number`,`apd.industry_type_cde` in `IN` clause or any other.

any idea how I can do this?

Comment: If you're working in Oracle and need an Oracle answer, why is this tagged with `mysql` and `tsql`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Tsql is langue which is used on all platform Ok got it man? and the other thing is is someone is worked on same thing is mysql that idea can be worked for reference you can see in accepted answer that man is working in mysql....

Comment: TSql is a *variant* of SQL that is present on Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase SQL Server. Other databases have their own variants of SQL, but those variants are not referred to as `tsql`. The standardized language is just called `sql`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i am working with mysql and postgresql the below works fine on both i think it will work on oracle too

```
WHERE (column1,column2) IN ( select col1,col2 .....rest of the query)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name   it will work for sure  and still if you don't believe me just try it with some sample data

Comment: Hmmm, the last time I tried that in MySQL it failed. But apparently this has changed.

Comment: yes it is version specific in 5.1.34 it wont work after 5.1.64 only it will

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WHERE apd.application_number in 
   (select apd.application_number FRoM ...)
OR
   apd.application_number in 
   (select apd.industry_type_cde FROM ...)
```

Comment: you have entered two different checks. In my case these two column are act like a composite key. I cant do this in your way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an union:

```
select apd.application_number 
from a_detail apd,a_type apt
where 
    apt.application_number=apd.application_number and 
    apt.identification_code=apd.identification_code and
    apt.guarantor_type='I'
UNION
select apd.industry_type_cde 
from a_detail apd,a_type apt
where 
    apt.application_number=apd.application_number and
    apt.identification_code=apd.identification_code and
    apt.guarantor_type='I'
```

Comment: you have entered two different checks. In my case these two column are act like a composite key. I cant do this in your way.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you had shown the table schema. However **`JOIN`** can simulate `IN` :)

```
 SELECT apd.first_name,
       apd.middle_name,
       apd.last_name,
       apd.first_thi_nme,
       apd.middle_thi_nme,
       apd.last_thi_nme
FROM applicant_detail apd
JOIN 
    (SELECT apd.application_number,
               apd.industry_type_cde
     FROM a_detail apd 
     INNER JOIN
     a_type apt
     ON apt.application_number=apd.application_number
       WHERE apt.identification_code=apd.identification_code
       AND apt.guarantor_type='I' ) as X
ON apd.application_number = CONCAT(X.application_number, X.industry_type_cde)
;
```

- ### [Visual representation of SQL JOINS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Comment: @user1387147 I see that you have accepted an answer, however if you are looking for a substitute for `in` then you may use the `join` as showed.

Comment: A JOIN is **not** a substitute for an IN clause. It does something different.